# What is the expected time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, randomized-algorithms

In the following algorithm $A[1..n]$ denotes an array $A$ of size $n$, of $n$ distinct integers. Func1() and Func2() are functions that run in $\mathcal O(\log n)$ and $\mathcal O(n)$ time, respectively.

```
Foo(A[1..n])
    if n == 1:
        return
    
    while (True) {
        Func1()
        i = random[1, 2, ..., n] \\ uniform random sampling from {1, 2, ..., n}
        if (A[i] is in the middle third of A[1..n]):
            break            
    }
    Func2()
    Foo(A[1..i])
    Foo(A[i+1..n])
```

Without the loop I can get easily $T(n) = \mathcal O(n) + \frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}(T(i) + T(n-i))$, but I'm not sure what to do with the loop. Would $$ T(n) = \frac{2}{3}\log n 
 + \frac{1}{3}\times \left(\mathcal O(n)+\frac{3}{n} \sum^{2n/3}_{i=n/3}(T(i) + T(n-i))\right)$$ be correct?

Comment: depends on how the sampling of `i` is done. It might be the case that the while loop doesn't break out

Comment: If n = 2, can A[I] be in the middle third of A[1..2]? Or is I = 1 in the first third, I = 2 in the last third, and nothing in the middle third at all?